# Get exact object from injected instance CDI

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

I have some DAOs like `UserDAO, ProductDAO` etc with no cdi annotations or qualifiers (they're `@Default` then). These classes implements abstract DAO:

```
public interface DAO {
    void update();
    void delete();
    void getById(long id);
}
```

So I receive all avaliable DAO implementations:

```
public class ClassToInjectIn {
    @Inject
    private Instance<DAO> allDAOs;
}
```

Now `allDAOs` contains this:

```
[UserDAO, {@Default(), @Any()}]
[ProductDAO, {@Default(), @Any()}]
```

For example, I need to get the UserDAO from this instance, but I can't.
I want to do it the way like this:

```
UserDAO user = allDAOs.get();
```

But it throws exception:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   javax.enterprise.inject.AmbiguousResolutionException: Too many beans
>   match, because they all have equal precedence.

So the **problem** is that I can't use lots of qualifiers because I have a lot of entities and they can be added later. I need one universal method that can find and extract the object with requested type how it was shown in example above. And it shouldn't use the class name or any string names to indecate the needed type or class. E.g. `public DAO getNeededDAO(String neededClassName)`. It has to dynamically detect the required type/class. Is it possible to do?

**UPDATE**

I need exactly this:

```
UserDAO user = chooseAndGetRequiredDAO();
```

So `chooseAndGetRequiredDAO()` has to understand that UserDAO type is required. It must to look for exist DAOs and choose UserDAO if finds. Maybe it should use reflecton or any DAO factory, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `allDAOs` field allows you to perform [programmatic lookup](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#programmatic_lookup) on all beans having the `DAO` type in their types set.
But to do a lookup you have to give a search request. In that particular case a combination of type and qualifiers.

```
UserDAO user = allDAOs.select(UserDao.class).get();
```

Comment: My god, it was so simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Either you:

- use `@Named`
- inject the actual interface, eg `UserDAO`, `OrderDAO`, ... (the right way)
- inject a `DAOFactory` with a method `T build(Class<T>)` that you invoke at runtime like this `factory.build(User.class).getById(id)` (I do **not** suggest this)

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps specialize your DAOs, if that is possible with a generic parameter:

```java
public interface DAO<T> {
   ...
}
```

You could then differentiate between different ones with the generic parameter. Although that only works for CDI beans, not for EJBs (I think)

```java
@Inject
private DAO<User> userDao;
```

If you really want *all* DAOs, you have to iterate the `allDAOs`. In your example:

```java
for(DAO dao: allDAOs) {
   ...do something with dao...
}
```

Comment: Read my update please. And I can't inject DAO with exact type.

Comment: Why not inject UserDAO directly then? Otherwise see other post with `select()`.